# bootstrap navbar doesn't set the active page when the brand is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen a ton of solutions for how to toggle the active class on navbar pages, but nothing addresses the issue of what happens when you set the navbar brand link to go to home page, and how to set the Home link to active in that case, while disabling previously active one. Here's the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header row">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarCollapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#!/">KitchBlocks</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#!/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!/purchase">Purchase</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!/download">Download</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.kiche.com/" style="padding:0"><img src="images/a.png" height="32" style="margin-top:1px" ></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here's the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
            $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

So again, to re-create the issue: Navigate to main page, by default "home" is active. Navigate to "download", and that becomes active. Hit the brand link which redirects to "home" but "download" is STILL active. Anyway to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple modification of your example. Working fiddle is [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/moyeen52/t2xcnh6g/3/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
        $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
    $(".navbar-brand").on("click", function(){
        $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $('.nav a[href="#!/"]').parent().addClass("active");
    });
});
```